# Javascript: Adding final element to array after for loop completes

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

**Explanation of Desired Results**

My source is over 30,000 lines of very structured text with incrementing front numbers followed by incrementing back numbers and separated by a colon. Stripping out the non-essentials, I am left with the following sourceArray, truncated for convenience :)

```
sourceArray = ["001:001", "001:002", "001:003", 
               "002:001", "002:002", 
               "003:001", "003:002"];
```

I am trying to count how many back numbers for each front number and push that to an array. In pseudocode, my final results should look like this:

```
myArray[totalNumberOf_001_Items, totalNumberOf_002_Items, totalNumberOf_003_Items]
```

Which in my simple example should give me a final value of:

```
[3, 2, 2]
```

**Problem and Question**

My for loop ends at the end of my data and I am therefore one element short in my array.

*How do I make an "extra pass" through the loop or is there another way to get the final element pushed to my array?*

```js
var sourceArray = ["001:001", "001:002", "001:003",
  "002:001", "002:002",
  "003:001", "003:002"
];
var myArray = [];
var frontCounter = 1;
var backCounter = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
  var text = sourceArray[i];
  var front = text.substr(0, 3);
  front = Number(front);
  var back = text.substr(4, 3);
  back = Number(back);

  if (front == frontCounter) {
    backCounter++;
  } else {
    myArray.push(backCounter - 1);
    backCounter = 2;
    frontCounter++;
  }
}
console.log(myArray); // result [3, 2]
```

Comment: `var i = 0; i <= sourceArray.length;` Off the top of my head I'm think add an `=`'s ; that'll add an extra pass in the loop

Comment: wouldn't the final value be `[3, 3, 1]` ?

Comment: From reading this: "I am trying to count how many back numbers for each front number" I thought it would be [3, 3, 1]

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal with `=` , the extra loop cause sourceArray[i] to become `undefined`.

Comment: @DulyKinsky Loop 1: myArray = [1], Loop 2: myArray = [2], Loop 3: myArray = [3] as expected. Then Loop 4 comes around and skips to the else statement. myArray = [3] as before. To compensate, backCounter is reset to 2. Loop 5: myArray = [3, 2]. This is a very simplified example. With my actual data limited to 5 front numbers I end up with something more like [31, 25, 21, 26]. However there is no push of the final element to the array.

Comment: Before we get into the code, I am getting confused because we have not yet established what is expected. What are you trying to find out about the data. How many times 001, 002, 003 appear in the front (before the :) of how many times they appear in the back(after the :)? Or is it more intricate than that; if so, please try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that you can use so that you don't have to go through the entire source of lines *(30,000)* . Use a while loop so that you can break as soon as you reach a `0`; use `Map` to store the unique number by making the index/frontnumber the `key` and make its `value` an object that serves as a counter to keep track of it's total. If the key exists, update the total; if it doesn't, create a new counter object. Then just return the `Map` by transforming it into the desired array by `map`'ing it to an array with only the totals.

```js
var sourceArray = ["001:001", "001:002", "001:003",
  "002:001", "002:002",
  "003:001", "003:002"
];

function getTotal(sourceArray) {

  let count = new Map();
  let update = item => count.get(item).total++;
  let create = item => count.set(item, {total: 1});

  const getItem = index => {
    let text = sourceArray[index];
    return text.substr(0, 3);
  }

  let index = -1;
  let start = 0;
  
  while (index != 0 && start < sourceArray.length) {
    index = getItem(start++);
    count.has(index) ? update(index) : create(index);
  }

  return [...count.values()].map(item => item.total);
}

console.log(getTotal(sourceArray));
```

Comment: Thank you. This does solve the problem. However, it creates a new one :). The answer I need is [3, 2, 2]. The loop should end when I run out of new front numbers. I can not have any 0 elements. Especially since my data is 30,000+ items long. It would create thousands of extra elements.

Comment: @BrianWilson so if there are 0 elements for say number `2` and 3 elements for `3` will this ever be a case `[3,0,2]` ??  You can filter out the `0`'s but then you'll lose the notion of value associated with index.

Comment: [3, 0, 3] is never a possibility. There are only positive integers.

Comment: @BrianWilson I've updated the code to fit the new needs

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object like below to keep track of how many times the the piece of text appear, the text would be the keys and as value the number of times they appear. From that you can build you array

```js
var sourceArray = ["001:001", "001:002", "001:003", 
                   "002:001", "002:002", 
                   "003:001", "003:002"]; 

var frontEncounters = {};

function updateFrontEncounters(frontEncounters, front){
    var keys = Object.keys(frontEncounters);
    if(keys.indexOf(front) == -1)
    {
        frontEncounters[front] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        frontEncounters[front] += 1;
    }
}

for(var item in sourceArray){
    var text = sourceArray[item];
    var front = text.substr(0, 3);
    var back = text.substr(4, 3);
    updateFrontEncounters(frontEncounters, front);  
}

var keys = Object.keys(frontEncounters);
var myArr = [];

for(var key in keys)
{
    myArr.push(frontEncounters[keys[key]])
}
console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object to store the "front" numbers along with their count.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
    var num = sourceArray[i].slice(0,3);
    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num]+1 : 1;
}
```

Once done, you can very easily convert that to an array:

```
var result = Object.keys(counts).map(function (key) {
    return counts[key];
});
```

With ES-2017, it is even easier:

```
var result = Object.values(counts)
```

**Working Snippet**:

```js
var sourceArray = ["001:001", "001:002", "001:003", 
                   "002:001", "002:002", 
                   "003:001", "003:002"]; 
var counts = {};

for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
    var num = sourceArray[i].slice(0,3);
    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num]+1 : 1;
}
console.log(counts);
var result = Object.keys(counts).map(function (key) {
    return counts[key];
});
console.log(result);

// ES-2017
//console.log(Object.values(counts));
```

Comment: This seemed to work as I was able to compile a master array with nested arrays of the correct length. However, they do not appear to always be in strict order.

Comment: @BrianWilson: Yes. Arrays are not guaranteed to be in order. This is why an object (*or an object array if you've multiple sources*) would be a better choice for you as it will allow you to query on key and you will be sure to have values associated with key.